# What is the difference between jQuery(function($) {}) and $(document).ready(function(){}) in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm new in jQuery community. I have used these two function and both works nicely.
Can anyone explain what is the difference between these.
And is there any difference between jQuery.trim() and $.trim function?

Answer (score 1):

There is no diffence, The first one is the shorter form of the second.

You can check the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/ready/):

> **All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:**
>
> $(document).ready(handler)
>
> $().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
>
> $(handler)

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

> All three of the following syntaxes are equivalent:
>
> $( document ).ready( handler ) $().ready( handler ) (this is not
>   recommended) $( handler )

Answer (score 0):

No difference, however it is [recommended](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) to use `$(document).ready()` when working with a team of less experienced developers. One reason for his is that it reminds less experienced JavaScript developers and CSS specialists that the code is executed only once the HTML document has been processed and rendered to the browser.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference, but using `$(document).ready` makes it look like your copying code out of some tutorial somewhere.

Also `jQuery.trim()` and `$.trim`, are also the exact same thing. `jQuery == $`